# Filter and Extract element from List of Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

I have a list of named tuple as below

```
record = [({
   "first_name":"nadbor",
   "last_name":"drozd",
   "occupation":"data scientist",
   "markingAgentUsed":[
      {
         "consumableLabelCode":"L",
          "amountUsed":{
            "amount" : 100,
            "unit": "litre"
          }
      },
     {
         "consumableLabelCode":"Y",
          "amountUsed":{
            "amount" : 300,
            "unit": "mililitre"
          }
      },
     {
         "consumableLabelCode":"0",
          "amountUsed":{
            "amount" : 999,
            "unit": "gallon"
          }
      }
   ]
})]


[{'first_name': 'nadbor', 'last_name': 'drozd', 'occupation': 'data scientist', 'markingAgentUsed': [{'consumableLabelCode': 'L', 'amountUsed': {'amount': 100, 'unit': 'litre'}}, {'consumableLabelCode': 'Y', 'amountUsed': {'amount': 300, 'unit': 'mililitre'}}, {'consumableLabelCode': '0', 'amountUsed': {'amount': 999, 'unit': 'gallon'}}]}]
```

I want to extract the values based on a input parameter of LabelCode, I want to extract the two values amount and unit.

for example if i pass O, I should get 999 and gallon as output.

Comment: Can you add the code that defines the named tuple. It's not clear looking at this what `Row` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
record = [({
   "first_name":"nadbor",
   "last_name":"drozd",
   "occupation":"data scientist",
   "markingAgentUsed":[
      {
         "consumableLabelCode":"L",
          "amountUsed":{
            "amount" : 100,
            "unit": "litre"
          }
      },
     {
         "consumableLabelCode":"Y",
          "amountUsed":{
            "amount" : 300,
            "unit": "mililitre"
          }
      },
     {
         "consumableLabelCode":"0",
          "amountUsed":{
            "amount" : 999,
            "unit": "gallon"
          }
      }
   ]
})]

userKey = '0'
for entry in record[0]['markingAgentUsed']:
    if entry['consumableLabelCode'] == userKey:
        print("Amount - {}".format(entry['amountUsed']['amount']) )
        print("Units - {}".format(entry['amountUsed']['unit']) )
```

Answer (score 2):

It is all about understanding the nesting of the data structure (which is not a named tuple, but a list of tuples of dictionaries with a list of dictionaries of which some keys are dictionaries themselves :-/ Few! This piece of code extracts what you ask for:

```
inp = '0'

for ma in record[0]['markingAgentUsed']:
    if ma['consumableLabelCode'] == inp:
        print(ma['amountUsed']['amount'], ma['amountUsed']['unit'])
```